# Optimize a multivariable function when the constraint is an inequality.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know how to optimize functions with given constraints when those constraints are equalities, i.e. $g(x, y) = c$ with Lagrange multipliers. However, I have a problem where the constraint is an inequality and I'm wondering how (or if) I could do this.

I'm trying to minimize the function $f(x) = (4x^2 + y^2)/4xy$ with $y > x > 0$. I'm aware that there are probably simpler ways to do this, but I'd like to know if it's doable with direct partial differentiation. Is there a way to reduce this to a typical problem with a constraint that can be solved with Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to introduce a new "slack" variable for each constraint such that the inequality becomes an equality when written in terms of the slack variable. In your case, we have $x>0\Leftrightarrow \exists s, x=s^2$ and $y>x\Leftrightarrow \exists t, y-x=t^2$, so the problem is equivalent to solving the 4-variable optimization in the variables $x,y,s,t$ subject to the constraints $x=s^2, y-x=t^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't $x = s^2$ imply that x can be zero, though?

Comment: @zaq good point, i suppose you could let $x=e^s$ instead

Comment: Aha! Thank you!